# Why have my Laravel 4.2 stack trace pages changed?

Tags: laravel, stack, trace

I've recently installed a fresh copy of Laravel 4.2 for a new project.

I've turned on debugging in `app/config/app.php`, set up my local environment in `bootstrap/start.php` and turned debugging on in `app/local/app.php`.

For some reason, my stack trace pages have changed. I can't find anything about them having officially changed, there's nothing in the upgrade guide...

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BzTi.png) of what it looks like. It's almost like an addition onto the normal "something went wrong" page, not like the orange/grey stack traces I've become used to.

To check, I created a whole new test project and the proper stack trace (albeit a different colour) is displayed, [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5ImT.png).

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run following `artisan` command from your `command prompt`:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

It supposed to ran after installation (I had same problem).

Comment: Great, thanks. I also had to run `composer update` for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised you two were able to get the problem solved with `artisan clear-compiled` and `composer update` alone. Neither of those work for me.

After some troubleshooting, I found there are changes made in Laravel 4.2.2 and 4.2.3 that cause the Whoops page to go wonky. I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4715) at github.

Changes introduced in 4.2.2 make the stack traces look [like the first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT4JY.png) @sanaco screenshot...

**Laravel 4.2.2:**

[image]

...then additional changes made in 4.2.3 make it look [the second one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM1kj.png):

**Laravel 4.2.3**

[image]